# iPhone Nav Bar Font

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, fonts, uinavigationbar, font-size

I'm trying to replicate an iphone style navbar in my mac app. But I just can't figure out what font (name and size) that the title in the navbar should be. Does anybody know what it is or have a way to figure it out? Thanks in advance.

Update: Here's a picture. I'm referring to the "Navigation bar" pointed out on top.
http://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/iPhone_UI_elements_sizes.jpg

Comment: Can you link to a screenshot of the sort of iPhone navbar you are talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I just figured it out! Helvetica Neue, as Ben pointed out, and then I used size 20. But then, to complete the look, you need to give it an embossed look. I did this by using this code:

```
[[myTextField cell] setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleLowered];
```

I found that here: http://whomwah.com/2009/03/11/replicating-apples-embossed-text-in-a-cocoa-app/

Now it looks right.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to iPhone 4, the font is Helvetica.  The iPhone 4 uses Helvetica Neue.
The point-size you want will depend on what you mean by 'navbar'.

Comment: I've tried Helvetica Neue, but it doesn't look right. I've tried several different font sizes to no avail. I've linked a picture to clear up what I was talking about, so maybe you could look at that.

Comment: Try _Helvetica Neue Bold_ - that's definitely the one.  I had a fiddle and it looked about right.  On the image you linked the word 'Title' on the navigation bar looks about font size 24.

Comment: Still not looking right for me. Here's a picture of what mine looks like with your font and size: [link](http://natmatproductions.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/screen-shot-2011-07-18-at-11-11-10-am.png?w=348)

Answer (score 0):

Replicate title label manually:

`UINavigationItem(Category)`

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold"  size:20.0f];
    CGSize textSize = [title sizeWithFont:font];
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height)];
    label.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    label.text = title;
    label.font = font;
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5f];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-1);
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self setTitleView:label];
    [label release];
}
```